# Is it strictly because of latency that the cloud computing revolution hasn't made it all the way to games yet?

Tags: networking

There are a number of Stack Exchange sites where this might potentially be applicable, and I'm not sure which one to pick really.

I was just looking at [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/415699/100669) concerning the essence of cloud computing, and it dawned on me: In some ways, there is some very, very real benefit that the ***successful*** application of cloud computing to playing games could bring.  In particular, if the games are installed on the cloud, not on your local machine, you wouldn't have to worry about upgrading your computer (or your phone) every five seconds.

However this model is not generally used for AAA video games, just for fairly small stuff that's pretty much on the scale of Adobe Flash apps.  So that brings up the question: Why are we still generally installing stuff of any scale locally onto our own personal computers, tablets, and phones?  Why are we not just playing it all directly off of some cloud servers instead?

The main thing that came to mind was latency.  (Of course there's also something fun about having a special console, like a Switch or a PS4, so we'll give some ground there.)  In terms of a PC or a phone, while this would be nice to have, having each and every individual button/keypress, mouse click, joystick movement, and so on have to be sent up to the cloud to be processed; then having to get the result back from the cloud to visually and audibly show the user what that did in the actual game - that may just be a little too much for today's infrastructure.  We have been playing MMOs in real time for quite a while now, but maybe the added functionality would just result in too much of a delay to keep everything in real time.

Or maybe not.  But in either case, is this the only holdup?  Is this the only reason we're still going to stuff like Steam and installing games on our computers, instead of just playing almost everything directly through Steam on a network cloud somewhere?

Comment: Don't forget that cloud computing is already used behind the scenes in the servers and associated support systems for many online multiplayer games. You don't have to go all the way to a Google Stadia style thin client to benefit from the scalability of cloud infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is currently latency, but it's a huge one. Unlike with movies or music, even a .2 second delay on your connection can make a game literally unplayable. I see you give the example of MMOs, but MMOs have a problem pretty much the same as this: even minor, fraction-second latency spikes can really make the game feel unresponsive and unfun.

A second big problem is that you need large amounts of bandwidth to stream games. Google Stadia and Geforce Now both have a requirement of at least 25 Megabit/second throughput connections, because they need to stream 60 FPS full HD content to your computer. This might seem like it's a relatively low barrier, but it's not. There are still many places, even in developed countries, where broadband is very expensive or even at all unavailable. For example, the United States has millions of households (roughly 1/4th of their country by latest statistics) without broadband internet. Many Americans live in rural areas where the commercial internet service providers have decided to do stuff like not cover those who live at the outskirts of villages and will only extend cables if the home owners pay for it, which can cost hundreds, sometimes thousands of dollars.

Related to acute bandwidth needs are long-term bandwidth needs. Both Stadia and Geforce Now use at least 10 GB of bandwidth per hour. That's an obscenely high amount for on-demand entertainment. Netflix uses 3 GB per hour. Spotify uses 40 MB per hour. Let's say I want to play Call of Duty: Modern Warfare. If I download it, it's 250 GB. That's a lot, but if I want to play it using cloud gaming, just playing an hour per day will get you to 300 GB per month. 2 hours per day and you're at 600 GB. For a HUGE amount of people, that's already pretty close to, if not significantly over their bandwidth caps, even if you ignore that they probably want to consume other content as well.

Finally, there's the problem of game availability and ownership. If I own a personal copy of a game on my computer, I can be fairly certain I can play that game regardless of whether my internet is available, especially for singleplayer games. With cloud gaming, you need to have high bandwidth internet accessible in order to play your game. You most likely won't be able to play with multiple people on the same connection, and other people using your connection to download stuff or watch streams will likely suffer.

A footnote on Stadia: Stadia has the additional issue that any game you wish to play on Stadia has to be bought from their store and cannot be taken offline afterwards. You are effectively tied to Google for these games, and if Google Stadia were to be closed down, you'd effectively lose access to these games. However, I don't think this is a problem with cloud gaming as much as it is a problem with Google's business model, and Geforce Now does not have this issue, because you pretty much play your own games.

Comment: While bandwidth is indeed an issue, the bandwidth needed for a 4k game is identical to the bandwidth needed to stream a 4k movie on Netflix.  What's happening with Cloud gaming is that the service is reading a stream of controller input commands from you and sending a simple video stream to you.  That second part is identical to what Netflix does.  The difference is that Netflix is sending things seconds or even minutes before you see it while a Cloud gaming service has to try to get those frames to you in milliseconds

Comment: Caveat: bandwidth depends on how much compression you use as well as the size

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy your question,

I believe the cloud computing is not entirely developed at cost point of view to relay all the game services just in the cloud, you will have to create a massive and global infrastructure plus this will impact the network egress and ingress costs.

Talking about latency I it could be a really serious speed bump the fact that there are areas where the ISP can just reach 20mbps. So as good as the game provider tries to invest, deliver and sync the content it will not be possible to make it right at 100%, adding the fact that not all the users will have the minimum infrastructure requirements to sync the game, they will have to create an adaptive sync depending on every user needs.

So from now the best option will be by doing some strange hybrid infrastructure by the hand of preconfigured hardware (Xbox, PlayStation)or any on-prem system.